# Unable to retrieve records before start of month - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I am trying to retrieve all records before the beginning of the current month. The following is the query i am trying.

```
select Date_of_receipt from str where 'Date_of_Receipt' < DATE_FORMAT((curdate() - dayofmonth(curdate()) + 1), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

I have two Date_of_receipt at 09/08/2014 and 09/08/2012. It should retrieve 09/08/2012 entry. But its giving blank. I executed,

```
select DATE_FORMAT((curdate() - dayofmonth(curdate()) + 1), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

and it returined 01/08/2014. So, can anyone tell where i am going wrong and oblige.

Edit 1:Tried

```
select Date_of_receipt from str where DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Date_of_Receipt, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') < DATE_FORMAT((curdate() - dayofmonth(curdate()) + 1), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Still not working!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have single quotes around the `Date_Of_Receipt`.  Hence, MySQL interprets it as a string.  That is the first problem.  So, this is a partial fix:

```
select Date_of_receipt
from str
where Date_of_Receipt < DATE_FORMAT((curdate() - dayofmonth(curdate()) + 1), '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

The next problem is that you should be comparing dates to dates, not to *strings*.  Assuming `Date_of_Receipt` is actually stored as a date/datetime, then simply do:

```
select Date_of_receipt
from str
where Date_of_Receipt < curdate() - interval dayofmonth(curdate()) day
```

Presumably you actually mean `<=` or something like that.  Subtracting the current day of the month from the current date puts you on the last day of the previous month.

EDIT:

If `Date_of_Receipt` is stored -- horror of horrors -- as a string, then you need to convert it to a date.  It is bad karma to store dates as strings.  After all, you see what happens when you try to compare them.  Try this:

```
select Date_of_receipt
from str
where str_to_date(Date_of_Receipt, '%d/%m/%Y') < curdate() - interval dayofmonth(curdate()) day
```

Comment: When you compare a date to a string, MySQL automatically converts the string to a date first.

Comment: Removed the single quotes and just comparing with '<' still not working!!

Comment: What is the data type of `Date_of_Receipt` and what are sample values?

Comment: The data type is varchar, hence in my edit, i have tried to convert it to date format and then use!!, Gordon, tried your edit mate, did not work :(

Comment: You need to do the comparison as a *date* not as a string.